# Building Menu recursively in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

### Problem

I recently discovered SwiftUI's [`OutlineGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/outlinegroup) in iOS 14 (I am using Xcode 12 beta 6 ). This works really well, either on its own or when using `List`, to compute "views and disclosure groups on demand from an underlying collection of tree-structured, identified data."

I.e. if you have a `struct` defined recursively, this works really well to build `DisclosureGroup` elements. However I am looking for something a little different that would allow me to build a "pull-down" (or hamburger) menu.

There's another control called [`Menu`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu), in iOS 14, which renders a "pull-down" (or hamburger) menu exactly as I would like :

[image]

However I can't seem to use the 2 together to build a dynamic `Menu` based on [data represented recursively](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/09/02/displaying-recursive-data-using-outlinegroup-in-swiftui/), for example :

```
struct Tree<Value: Hashable>: Hashable {
    let value: Value
    var children: [Tree]? = nil
}
```

And menus built in the following manner :

```
struct SideMenu: View {    
    var body: some View {        
        Menu {
            Button(action: {}) {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                Text("Profile")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            Button(action: {}) {
                Image(systemName: "person.3")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                Text("Family Members")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            Button(action: {}) {
                Image(systemName: "calendar")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                Text("Events")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
        }
    }
}
```

### Question

Is there a way to build `Menu` from recursive data, similar to what is done with `OutlineGroup` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like enums to represent trees, to avoid impossible or inconsistent states.
Furthermore, you need a recursive UI function call, but using methods makes the compiler fails for me (Xcode 12 beta 6), so instead I separated the menu parts in different views and this seems to work. Now you have a completely dynamic menu that can built from your ViewModel.

```
import SwiftUI

enum ViewEvent {
    case profileTapped
    case familyMembersTapped
    case eventsTapped
    case foldersTapped
    case deletedItemsTapped
}

struct MenuItem: Identifiable {
    var id: String { return text }
    let text: String
    let systemImage: String?
    let action: ViewEvent?
}

enum MenuContent: Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        switch self {
        case let .item(item): return item.id
        case let .submenu(text, _): return text
        }
    }

    case item(MenuItem)
    indirect case submenu(text: String, content: [MenuContent])
}

struct ViewState {
    let menu: [MenuContent]
    let content: String

    static var `default`: ViewState {
        .init(
            menu: [
                .item(MenuItem(text: "Profile", systemImage: "person", action: .profileTapped)),
                .item(MenuItem(text: "Family Members", systemImage: "person.3", action: .familyMembersTapped)),
                .item(MenuItem(text: "Events", systemImage: "calendar", action: .familyMembersTapped)),
                .submenu(text: "More", content: [
                    .item(MenuItem(text: "Folders", systemImage: "folder.fill", action: .foldersTapped)),
                    .item(MenuItem(text: "Deleted", systemImage: "trash.fill", action: .deletedItemsTapped))
                ])
            ],
            content: "Content")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var viewState: ViewState

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 16) {
            AppMenu(contents: viewState.menu) {
                Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
            }

            Text("Content")
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct AppMenuItem: View {
    let item: MenuItem

    func dispatch(_ action: ViewEvent) {
        // todo: call viewModel.dispatch
        print("Sending action \(action)")
    }

    init(item: MenuItem) {
        self.item = item
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            item.action.map { action in dispatch(action) }
        }) {
            item.systemImage.map { systemImage in
                Image(systemName: systemImage)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .imageScale(.large)
            }

            Text(item.text)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .font(.headline)
        }
    }
}

struct AppSubmenu: View {
    let text: String
    let contents: [MenuContent]

    var body: some View {
        AppMenu(contents: contents) {
            HStack {
                Text(text)
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AppMenu<Label: View>: View {
    let label: () -> Label
    let contents: [MenuContent]

    init(contents: [MenuContent], @ViewBuilder label: @escaping () -> Label) {
        self.contents = contents
        self.label = label
    }

    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            ForEach(contents) { content in
                // In case this is an item
                if case let .item(item) = content {
                    AppMenuItem(item: item)
                }

                // In case this is a submenu
                if case let .submenu(text, contents) = content {
                    AppSubmenu(text: text, contents: contents)
                }
            }
        } label: { label() }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great. The compiler is complaining if I move some of the Action / State definition under an AppMenu extension. But otherwise, this does exactly what I was looking for : recursive traversal of the menu data. Thanks !

Comment: It would be nice to use func with ViewBuilder instead of a different View, so having everything in the same View structure would allow to reuse same View Model. But the compiler is crashing when I try that on Xcode 12 beta 6, when I have time I'm gonna open a FB.

Comment: It doesn't need to be so complicated. Just follow the normal recursive method, and the type of the return function is menu or button wrapped in AnyView. Of course, Foreach's method was used.

Comment: This worked really well and can be ported to different data types easily.